# Windows in GNOME stuck at top left corner of desktop

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm using GNOME 2.16 on Red Hat.  I was doing some work in the Terminal and, by accident I entered a command that made the windows for all programs to be stuck to the top-left corner of the desktop with no easy way to disable it. I don't even know what command I entered. Does anyone know of a way to disable that?

Comment: GNOME is not an OS. It's also not developed by Red Hat.

Comment: When did he mean GNOME is an OS? Or that it was developed by Red Hat? Douche.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a temporary setting that may go away (go back to normal) when you reboot. Have you rebooted?

Comment: The OP might not even need to reboot. Try: pressing `ctrl-alt-backspace` to restart the X server or logout by another method, and then log back in.